# use luigi.DateParameter in a run function of a Luigi Orchestrator Task

Tags: python, orchestration, luigi

I have the following python code using the Luigi Orchestrator.

```
class AggregateArtists(luigi.Task):
    date = luigi.DateParameter(default=date.today() - timedelta(days=1))

    def requires(self):
        return []

    def run(self):
        ...
```

I want to use the date parameter in my `run()` function. The problem is that I don't know what type it is. In the doc, it seems that this parameter is a `datetime.date`, so I should be able to use the method `self.date.strftime()`. But this method is not avalaible for `DateParameters`.

My questions are:

- How can I use the variable date of my code within my run function? What type is it? A string, a datetime.date or something else?
- At some point, I need to convert this date to a string of the form YYYYMMDD, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete but I'll guess the rest is like the following. You must have an error somewhere because it works: `DateParameter` returns a value that is a python date. See [luigi source code for details](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/parameter.py#L302).

My `tasks/foo.py`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import luigi


class AggregateArtists(luigi.Task):
    date = luigi.DateParameter(default=date.today() - timedelta(days=1))

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("/tmp/foobar.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as out_file:
            out_file.write(self.date.strftime("%Y%m%d") + "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    luigi.run()
```

Running the task:

```
$ python tasks/foo.py AggregateArtists --local-scheduler

DEBUG: Checking if AggregateArtists(date=2015-12-03) is complete
INFO: Scheduled AggregateArtists(date=2015-12-03) (PENDING)
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 1 processes
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 1
INFO: [pid 21831] Worker Worker(salt=179482616, workers=1, host=matagus-laptop, username=matagus, pid=21831) running   AggregateArtists(date=2015-12-03)
INFO: [pid 21831] Worker Worker(salt=179482616, workers=1, host=matagus-laptop, username=matagus, pid=21831) done      AggregateArtists(date=2015-12-03)
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
INFO: Done
INFO: There are no more tasks to run at this time
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=179482616, workers=1, host=matagus-laptop, username=matagus, pid=21831) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
```

Print the contents of the output file:

```
$ cat /tmp/foobar.txt 
20151203
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DateParameter' object has no attribute 'strftime'